# Safari not requesting srcset images on resize

Tags: html, safari, mobile-safari, responsive-images, srcset

I want to provide [responsive images](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/responsive-images-101-definitions/), for that I use srcset attribute.

```
<img 
    src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_480/group.jpg" 
    alt=""
    srcset="
        https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_480/group.jpg 480w,
        https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_750/group.jpg 750w,
        https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_1334/group.jpg 1334w,
        https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_1536/group.jpg 1536w,
        https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_2048/group.jpg 2048w
    "
>
```

Chrome and android works as expected; in a mobile in portrait it will load a 'small' image, just the needed to fill the width, if you turn the phone it will request a new image according to the new width.

In Chrome inspector tool selecting an iOS devices (iPhone 6, iPad) works well:

[image]

But Safari both desktop and mobile doesn't request a new image on resize/turn device. But it does request the correct image on reload.

I tried with Safari 9.1.2 and 11.0, iPhone 6 (iOS 10.3.2), iPhone 6s (iOS 11.0) and iPad Air 2 (iOS 11.0).

Does Safari have still a lack of support for srcset?
It is [suppose to be fully supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset).

Test yourself at [codepen](https://codepen.io/M1k3l/full/XaejJp/).
[Code at codepen](https://codepen.io/M1k3l/pen/XaejJp?editors=1000) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current state of srcset is such that I am not entirely sure what you are looking for is a requirement.

This article by Jason Grigsby entitled [State of Responsive Images in 2017](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/state-of-responsive-images-2017/) helps explain that while some of this ambiguity is by design to promote competition between browsers, some of this could probably be clarified better:

> ...the different behavior causes confusion. The most common question I hear is from people testing srcset in Safari and not seeing new images download as the viewport size changes.
>
> There is nothing that says that the browser needs to download new images as the viewport changes. In fact, it probably doesn’t make sense to download a new image if the browser already has a larger version of it and can downsize it.
> So while this may be a feature and not a bug, we could do a better job setting expectations for developers.

In the meantime I would be wary of quoting full support for srcset just yet. In my recent experience it has been anything but.

Comment: I recognize this problem unfortunately I do not have a solution yet. Chrome expects as it should be. Now that WordPress ships with srcset as default for it's images this causes a lot of responsive pages to break.

Answer (score 0):

Nor does it use 1.1x or higher srcset images on 110% zoom etc. as Chrome does properly.

To make it simple: When I use zoom, the images are unsharp in Safari and sharp in Chrome. Nopthing to discuss there. Safari loses, Chrome wins.