# <picture> Tag - Ignoring <source> Tags && Falling back to <img> on iPad / Safari (Desktop)

Tags: html, ipad, safari, responsive, srcset

I am struggling to solve an isssue I have with iPad responsive images and could not find a solution here. I have the following HTML5 code applied to a banner to have it responsive.

```
<picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 1081px)" srcset="desktop-image">
   <source media="(min-width: 661px)" srcset="tablet-image">
   <source media="(min-width: 0px)" srcset="mobile-image">
   <img src="desktop-image">
</picture>
```

**Expected Behavior:** Responsively displays and falls back to appropriate `<source>` on iPad

**Current Behavior:** Responsively displays and falls back to appropriate `<source>` on iOS mobile Safari but not tablet/iPad. `<picture>` not responding responsively to viewport width

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you post the browser versions for the desktop/devices you're testing against? You can better diagnose the issue knowing whether or not the `<picture>` tag is definitively supported, which may or may not be the case.

Comment: IOS / Safari version was 9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com) to see which of the newer **HTML5** elements are supported whenever there's a doubt. Sometimes it can really help debug some rather perplexing Safari or IE-specific support issues.

[image: <picture> Not Supported by iOS < v9.2]

In this specific scenario it could be a combined issue of any of the following:

- the lack of support of the `<picture>` element
- using only the `min-width` versus `max-width` property
- not using responsive measurements to detect the correct viewport size for fallbacks (**e.g.:** *using `50vw` for instance*)

This Google [responsive images post](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images) may also help you debug a few more combination possibilities to correctly fallback to the desired image for each of your screen sizes.

Hope this helps! This question may be a possible duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671200/safari-not-requesting-srcset-images-on-resize?rq=1) and you may find some help here as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. This definitely is a compatibility issue with Safari versions